# Multi-row tab bar in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

Firefox Quantum [breaks tab mix plus and tab kit](https://superuser.com/a/42393/133195).  Is there any way to get a multi-row tab bar in Firefox Quantum?

If possible, I'm looking for a supported, stable solution, that is unlikely to break at the next new version.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Preferably, yes, so that it's unlikely to break in the next upgrade.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm afraid that the answer to your question is probably "no."  Unless you are willing to experiment just a bit with a solution like the one you already saw [here](https://superuser.com/a/1280151/650163), at this time there isn't a supported solution.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Together with Run5ks "no" that's a useful answer, and answers are more secure to the future than comments (in particular in case this question remains without upvotes).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an updated userChrome.css that shows icons and hides the ugly scrollbar in the tab rows

**UPDATE:** Newer Firefox versions changed userChrome behavior again, now I've taken the script directly from here (with a minor change to the max rows and tab width): https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/multi-row_tabs.css:

```
/* Source file https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/tree/master/chrome/multi-row_tabs.css made available under Mozilla Public License v. 2.0
See the above repository for updates as well as full license text. */

/* Makes tabs to appear on multiple lines */
/* Tab reordering will not work and can't be made to work */
/* You can use multi-row_tabs_window_control_patch.css to move window controls to nav-bar*/

/* You might want to move tabs-new-tab-button outside tabs toolbar for smoother behavior */

/* Change the --multirow-n-rows to change maximum number of rows before the rows will start to scroll  */

:root{
    --multirow-n-rows: 6;
    --multirow-tab-min-width: 150px;
    --multirow-tab-dynamic-width: 1; /* Change to 0 for fixed-width tabs using the above width. */
}

/* Scrollbar can't be clicked but the rows can be scrolled with mouse wheel */
/* Uncomment the next line if you want to be able to use the scrollbar with mouse clicks */

/* #tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox{ -moz-window-dragging: no-drag } */

/* Uncommenting the above makes you unable to drag the window from empty space in the tab strip but normal draggable spaces will continue to work */

#tabbrowser-tabs{
  min-height: unset !important;
  padding-inline-start: 0px !important
}

@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml){
  #scrollbutton-up~spacer,
  #scrollbutton-up,
  #scrollbutton-down{ display: var(--scrollbutton-display-model,initial) }

  scrollbox[part][orient="horizontal"]{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(var(--tab-min-height) * var(--multirow-n-rows));
    scrollbar-color: currentColor transparent;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
  }
}

#tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox{
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  display: block;
  --scrollbutton-display-model: none;
}

.tabbrowser-tab{ height: var(--tab-min-height); }

#tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab[pinned]{
  position: static !important;
  margin-inline-start: 0px !important;
}

.tabbrowser-tab[fadein]:not([pinned]){
  min-width: var(--multirow-tab-min-width) !important;
  flex-grow: var(--multirow-tab-dynamic-width);
  /*
  Uncomment to enable full-width tabs, also makes tab dragging a tiny bit more sensible
  Don't set to none or you'll see errors in console when closing tabs
  */
  /*max-width: 100vw !important;*/
}

.tabbrowser-tab > stack{ width: 100%; height: 100% }

#alltabs-button,
:root:not([customizing]) #TabsToolbar #new-tab-button,
#tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox > spacer,
.tabbrowser-tab::after{ display: none !important }
```

**Update July 7th 2020:** UserChrome behavior has changed once again for FF78+, please update to the above or check the Github page for source CSS.

Comment: April 3rd, 2019. Firefox is still unusable since there are still no multi-row tab extensions. Unbelievable how badly they crippled the browser with their extensions "upgrade". Sad.  It's been like what... 2 years now?  I'm so sick of scrolling 300 tabs across a single row.

Comment: Firefox is useless without multiple tab rows. Nov 3, 2020. No solution.  WOW. I'm back. Hi.
It's SHAMEFUL what Firefox has done to users by ruining this feature.

Comment: @Coruscate5 Could you please be more precise on how to use this CSS file?

Answer (score 4):

I tried looking for alternatives for this too and found no real options but to use a combination of addons:

I'm now using [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus-webextension) (WebExtensions) and the [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab) addons, along with [Session Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-sync/), using a combination of those I can make a more bearable  experience the tab management.

The **tree style tab** allows for a good alternative to the multirow feature due to the width of monitors and current resolutions, listing several tabs at the sidebar, the **session sync** improves the management via grouping of tabs in windows sessions and **tab mix plus webextensions** allows for related pages to stay in the same window. It's obviously not a multirow setup, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I agree. Despite using an upright (hence narrow) monitor, with F1 key to show/hide the sidebar, I find `Tree Style Tab` quite bearable -- actually better than `TabMix Plus` in some respects, because you get (and can form yourself as well) groups of tabs that can be collapsed, which makes it quite scalable.

Comment: As I use a vertical orientation of screen, TST doesn't really help. Unless there's an option for having it at the top of the screen somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution, with tab movement support is:
[Izheil's Multirow tabs](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/tree/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/Multirow%20tabs)

Comment: Link-only answer should be avoided whenever possible.
If you can provide at least a short step by step list that would help.

Comment: A short step by step list is to install the project by the link above. And it's not 'Link-only' answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with https://superuser.com/a/1480226/460302 that [Izheil's Multirow Tabs](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/tree/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/Multirow%20tabs) is the most promising means of obtaining multirow tabs in FireFox.  However, that answer does not tell how to implement the solution.  Here is some background:

First, Izheil states that his Javascript-based solution *Works with Firefox 69-70*.  I can confirm that it ***does not* work with *Firefox 68.2.0 esr*** (the latest ESR as of this writing, 10/23/19) under Windows 10.  However, Izheil provides several fully automated workarounds for Windows installations (see below).

Second, Izheil states [sic],

> Mozilla finally removed all XBL bindings from firefox, so in advance
>   of the removal of the posibility to inject JS scripts through
>   userchrome.xml, I decided to update the patching method to another one
>   that doesn't rely on this.

Basically this means he is no longer relying on userchrome.xml as an installation method.  To deploy using the new Javascript-based solution you need to [patch Firefox to enable JS injection](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/blob/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/JS%20Loader/Readme.md).  This is probably an excellent innovation, but it does involve multiple manual steps, including [clearing one's FF startup cache](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/blob/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/Readme.md) following each install.

However, if you wish to keep using XBL bindings (which seems the only option with FF versions prior to 69), **you may accomplish this automatically** using one of several Windows batch scripts currently included in Izheil's repository.  To use this method,

1. Download and extract https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/archive/master.zip
2. Navigate to the extracted file's *Installers* directory
3. Read the file titled *READ BEFORE RUNNING ANY BATCH FILE.txt*
4. Select and execute one of the .bat files found in this directory
5. Restart FireFox and leave a comment to this answer with your results, including Windows and FireFox versions.