# Firefox 78: change bookmark bar color in userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, colors, css

I have this in my `userChrome.css`:

```
#main-window #PersonalToolbar {
    background-color: green !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

After upgrade from Firefox 68.x to 78.3, this no longer has any effect, and my bookmark bar is grey. How can I change it to green, as I had done for version 68 ?

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful. It is always good to provide feedback.

Comment: @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio - sorry, but I don't understand your answer. What exactly do I have to change, to get back green background for bookmark toolbar? The code as posted above has no effect.

Comment: Try installing [the patcher](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/releases), which is useful on other counts as well, and see if it has any interaction with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not load `userChrome.css` or `userContent.css` by default for versions later 68. To change this default setting type `about:config` in addressbar and  confirm the appeared warning window and search for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` and enable it by clicking on two head arrow in the end of the line. Then restart Firefox. I hope it helps but I couldn't run the above `userChrome.css`. (I never used `userChrome.css` before.)

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40399376/6576302) for same problem.

---

**Edit:**  I don't know why your css code has no effect now (for FF +69) but the following does the same work:

```
#PlacesToolbarItems toolbarbutton[container="true"] .toolbarbutton-icon,
:-moz-any(
 #PlacesToolbarItems,
 #PlacesChevronPopup,
 #BMB_bookmarksPopup,
 #bookmarksMenu)

:-moz-any(#bookmarks-view, #historyTree, #editBMPanel_folderTree, #placesList, #placeContent) treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container) {
 fill: green !important;
 background-color: white !important;
}
```

[See here](https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html#colorbookmarkfolder) for complete code.

Comment: thanks, but `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` is already set to `true`. Besides, I can change other attributes in `userChrome.css`, so I am sure it is not ignored.

Comment: Sorry that my answer was not helpful. Could you tell me where `userChrome.css` file is exactly? Is it : `C:\Users\UeserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\chrome\ `

Comment: the file location is: `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxx.default/chrome/userChrome.css`. How does this help us solve the problem?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that the `css` file is in correct directory otherwise it doesn't work. Are you sure it is `~/.mozilla` and not `~/mozilla`? Try this`%\AppData%` and find the `mozilla` folder if your OS is `win10`.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you posted, in my `userChrome.css`, worked for me in FF81 under Ubuntu 20.
So just guessing what can help you make it work, I mention that I have installed a couple of fixes for tabs, not sure why it would affect the behavior of the bookmarks bar.

1. I used a previous version of [this CSS](https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/multi-row_tabs.css) by MrOtherGuy.
   Also mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/gefhvw/how_to_get_multirow_tab_bar_with_ff_75/fpn8al6/) and in [Multi-row tab bar in Firefox Quantum](https://superuser.com/questions/1351717/multi-row-tab-bar-in-firefox-quantum).
   Note that as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1378850/245595), starting with FF78 things changed again.
   For these purposes, the link to the CSS in Github should be up to date.
   (Note: I did not try [the Firemrt alternative](https://github.com/aplab/firemrt))
2. Most likely due to the changes in FF78, I saw some of the functionality for tabs broken.
   Instead of trying the updated version of the CSS above (had I known about it, the FF78 issue, etc., perhaps I would have gone that other way)
   I applied [the patcher](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/releases) by Izheil to fix the multirow tabs, which also provides  click and drag for tabs (long due!).
   Quoted also [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/gefhvw/how_to_get_multirow_tab_bar_with_ff_75/fpok02c/).

I added the lines you posted at the bottom, and now I see bookmark bar coloring works. Hope this helps you.

Notes:

1. You can have multi row bookmarks bars, see [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1281704) and [this](https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks/blob/master/chrome/multi-row_bookmarks.css) (also by MrOtherGuy!).
   Perhaps their contents also helps.
2. [This](https://techne.alaya.net/?p=19043) may also be useful.
3. Izheil also has [a lot of CSS tweaks](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/tree/FF81/CSS%20tweaks).
   Many of them for the bookmarks bar.
4. Just as a general reference [the site by Jefferson Scher](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html) is quite useful.